# Spark in HA: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.curator.utils.PathUtils.validatePath(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, nosuchmethoderror

I'm trying to setup HA for Spark 1.5.2 in standalone mode (via zookeeper). When starting spark, I'm getting this exception. Looks like an incompatibility issue. However I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
15/12/14 10:42:27 ERROR ErrorMonitor: Uncaught fatal error from thread [sparkMaster-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] shutting down ActorSystem [sparkMaster]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.curator.utils.PathUtils.validatePath(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
        at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.leader.LeaderLatch.<init>(LeaderLatch.java:147)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.leader.LeaderLatch.<init>(LeaderLatch.java:125)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.ZooKeeperLeaderElectionAgent.start(ZooKeeperLeaderElectionAgent.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.ZooKeeperLeaderElectionAgent.<init>(ZooKeeperLeaderElectionAgent.scala:34)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.ZooKeeperRecoveryModeFactory.createLeaderElectionAgent(RecoveryModeFactory.scala:74)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master.onStart(Master.scala:165)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$preStart$1.apply$mcV$sp(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnv.org$apache$spark$rpc$akka$AkkaRpcEnv$$safelyCall(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1.preStart(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:99)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundPreStart(Actor.scala:472)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1.aroundPreStart(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:92)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:580)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:456)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:263)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
15/12/14 10:42:27 ERROR ActorSystemImpl: Uncaught fatal error from thread [sparkMaster-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] shutting down ActorSystem [sparkMaster]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.curator.utils.PathUtils.validatePath(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
        at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.leader.LeaderLatch.<init>(LeaderLatch.java:147)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.leader.LeaderLatch.<init>(LeaderLatch.java:125)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.ZooKeeperLeaderElectionAgent.start(ZooKeeperLeaderElectionAgent.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.ZooKeeperLeaderElectionAgent.<init>(ZooKeeperLeaderElectionAgent.scala:34)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.ZooKeeperRecoveryModeFactory.createLeaderElectionAgent(RecoveryModeFactory.scala:74)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master.onStart(Master.scala:165)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$preStart$1.apply$mcV$sp(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnv.org$apache$spark$rpc$akka$AkkaRpcEnv$$safelyCall(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1.preStart(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:99)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundPreStart(Actor.scala:472)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1.aroundPreStart(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:92)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:580)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:456)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:263)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Comment: Check the version of your cluster and the libraries that you are using!

Comment: Spark 1.5.2. Hadoop 2.6.0. Zookeeper 3.4.5

Answer (score 0):

Use same curator version as of spark

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
            <artifactId>curator-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across with this error when trying to setup highly available *Spark 2.4.7* with *Hadoop 3.3.0*. Downgrading Hadoop version to *3.2.2* solved the problem.